# Netty version not consistent

Tags: java, netty

As shown in the figure, I introduced `netty-all` of version `4.1.49.final` in the project, but other components are version `4.1.92.final`. I tried many methods and directly introduced 4.1.49 locally in this module. .Final version of netty-all does not work, how do I solve it?

[image]

I want all netty's components to be version 4.1.94.Final

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is this a picture of?  Some IDE?  How are you managing your dependencies?  By hand (via the IDE)?  Using a build tool such as Gradle or Maven that understands dependencies?

Comment: Also, you seem to be confusing `4.1.94` and `4.1.49`.  That may just be a typo ... or not.  Because it is hard to understand what you are actually asking here.